# How to fix error: "Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2 [[{{node Squeeze}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to build a speech recognition model that can recognize the wakewords *"red on"*, *"red off"*, *"blue on"* and *"blue off"*. So far I could record my wake words with the software Audacity choosing as Encodiung Signed 16-bit PCM. I also followed the steps suggested by [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio#import_the_speech_commands_dataset). This is my code:

```
#Dataset path and view possible Voice Commands
data_dir = pathlib.Path('/content/test')

for name in listdir(data_dir):
     if isdir(join(data_dir, name)):
       print(name)

#Create a list for all keyword
commands = np.array(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir)))
commands = commands[commands != 'README.md']
print('Commands:', commands)

#Extract the audio files into a list and mix them.
filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/*/*')
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)
num_samples = len(filenames)
print('Number of total examples:', num_samples)
print('Number of examples per label:',
      len(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir/commands[0]))))
print('Example file tensor:', filenames[0])

#Divide the files in the ratio 80:10:10 into training, validation and test #sets. i have only 14 audios

train_files = filenames[:10]
val_files = filenames[10: 10+ 2 ]
test_files = filenames[-2:]
print('Training set size', len(train_files))
print('Validation set size', len(val_files))
print('Test set size', len(test_files))

#Reading audio files and their labels

def decode_audio(audio_binary):
  audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
  return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)

#The label for each WAV file is its parent directory.
def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)

  # Note: You'll use indexing here instead of tuple unpacking to enable this 
  # to work in a TensorFlow graph.
  return parts[-2]

#Let's define a method that takes the filename of the WAV file and outputs #a tuple containing audio and labels for the monitored training.

def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
  return waveform, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)



#Let's look at some audio waveforms with their corresponding names.
rows = 3
cols = 3
n = rows*cols
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 12))
for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds.take(n)):
  r = i // cols
  c = i % cols
  ax = axes[r][c]
  ax.plot(np.squeeze(audio.numpy()))
  ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, 0.2))
  label = label.numpy().decode('utf-8')
  ax.set_title(label)

plt.show()
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-197-3b45fddd6496> in <module>()
      3 n = rows*cols
      4 fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 12))
----> 5 for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds.take(n)):
      6   r = i // cols
      7   c = i % cols

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[{{node Squeeze}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Comment: How are you defining `waveform_ds`? It seems that the error could be most likely related to that. Include the related code in your question so we could take a peek into it.

Comment: thanks for the remark. I just put the complete code